# Using R, what are the equivalents of methods in other languages

Tags: r, methods

In languages such as Java and Eiffel, there is a divide between functions (returning a value) and methods, groups of transformative statements. So a method would be something like:
public main blah NAMEOFMETHOD(x) {
   STATEMENT/COMMAND
   STATEMENT/COMMAND
   STATEMENT/COMMAND
}

R has functions as basic to the language, but there is no obvious way of making a method (I think). Do I just put groups of commands in a class?  (I programmed years ago with Eiffel and Java, but am now using R for statistics and am extending my work with some programming - or is it coding you call it now?!)

Old guy relearning. Please be gentle.

Comment: What makes you think Java makes a difference between methods and functions? In fact, Java only knows methods.

Comment: If you are trying to learn R's object oriented programming tools, read the OO field guide chapter [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz) (and probably the whole book).

Answer (score 1):

R is a functional programming language. It's important to understand that there is technically no real difference between a function (with possible side-effects such as generating a plot) and a method.

The only difference is the absence of a "return value".

A Java method with signature

```
void doSomething()
```

(wich misses a `return`) can be implemented in R as

```
doSomething <- function(){
  # Do something here
  return(invisible(NULL))
}
```

where `NULL` is the return value ("nothing") and `invisible` instructs R not to automatically print this result to the console.

`return(invisible(NULL))` is equivalent to the shorter statement `return(invisible())` and, if it's the last line of code in your function, as it should be, also equivalent to `invisible()` because R auto-returns the result of the last computation in the function body.

Comment: Instead of the verbose `return(invisible(NULL))` you could just as well write `invisible()`. In fact, the first one is pretty un-functional.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Good to know, but at least the `return` is something I always want to keep so I can quickly see all exit points and what exactly is returned (I've ruined a few lapply's already by printing diagnostic info after the computation and forgetting about adding a proper return value^^ -- very bad with computation times > 8 hours)